# ng-if check if array is empty

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

The API I am working with returns this if there are no items in the array

```
items: []
```

If there are items in the array it returns something like

```
items: [
  {
    name: 'Bla'
  }
]
```

In my template I believe I need to use ng-if to either show/hide an element based on whether there is data in there or not.

```
<p ng-if="post.capabilities.items"><strong>Topics</strong>: <span ng-repeat="topic in post.capabilities.items">{{topic.name}}</p>
```

However I could be totally off base as this is my first time working in Angular, and there may be a much better way to do what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 128, accepted):

`post.capabilities.items` will still be defined because it's an empty array, if you check `post.capabilities.items.length` it should work fine because `0` is falsy.

Answer (score 55):

Verify the `length` property of the array to be greater than `0`:

```
<p ng-if="post.capabilities.items.length > 0">
   <strong>Topics</strong>: 
   <span ng-repeat="topic in post.capabilities.items">
     {{topic.name}}
   </span>
</p>
```

Arrays (objects) in JavaScript are truthy values, so your initial verification `<p ng-if="post.capabilities.items">` evaluates always to `true`, even if the array is empty.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work if the array is `null` or `undefined` - I get a runtime error.

Comment: @Dai Did you figure out a way for null arrays?

Comment: As the accepted answer points out, just use: ng-if="post.capabilities.items.length"  Then null, undefined and 0 length all evaluate to false.

Answer (score 40):

To overcome the `null` / `undefined` issue, try using the `?` operator to check existence:

```
<p ng-if="post?.capabilities?.items?.length > 0">
```

- Sidenote, if anyone got to this page looking for an ***Ionic Framework*** answer, ensure you use `*ngIf`:

  ```
  <p *ngIf="post?.capabilities?.items?.length > 0">
  ```

Answer (score 1):

*this is the solution  :*

```js
 <div *ngIf="post.capabilities.items.length > 0 && post.capabilities.items[0] !== '' "> ..... </div>
```

checks whether post.capabilities.items has a length greater than zero and ensures that the first item in the array is not an empty string. This ensures that content is displayed only if there are post.capabilities.items available and the first item in the list isn't an empty string .

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, doing this on the HTML template proved difficult so I decided to use an event to call a function on TS and then check the condition. If true make condition equals to true and then use that variable on the ngIf on HTML

```
    emptyClause(array:any) {


        if (array.length === 0) {
            // array empty or does not exist

            this.emptyMessage=false;

    }else{

            this.emptyMessage=true;
        }
}
```

HTML

```
        <div class="row">

        <form>
            <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1"></div>
            <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-10">
        <div [hidden]="emptyMessage" class="alert alert-danger">

            No Clauses Have Been Identified For the Search Criteria

        </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1"></div>
        </form>
```